# How can I tell if my controller action is being called from another controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any easy way to distinguish between an ASP.NET MVC controller action being hit "directly" due to a client web browser request, and being hit by virtue of a `Controller.RedirectToAction` call or a `RedirectToRoute` result?

Comment: Why do you care? There may be a better solution to the problem than trying to distinguish this.

Comment: I have an attribute on my actions to indicate if the page should only be served under SSL. If it should, but the request was made under plain old http then I redirect the current request to SSL. So far, so good. But in certain cases, the same action may be called from another controller action. In this case, I do not want to perform the redirection. There are a few refactorings that I could do to seperate out these concerns, but I just wondered if there is any easy way of detecting the "source" of the action.

Comment: In straight HTTP, there isn't. You can hack around it with Session/TempData, as others have suggested below, but there's no *definitive* way to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, put a value in TempData

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        // ... do stuff ...
        TempData["SomeKey"] = "SomeController.SomeAction";
        return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherAction", "SomeOtherController");
    }
}

public class SomeOtherController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeOtherAction()
    {
        if (TempData.ContainsKey("SomeKey"))
        {
            // ... do stuff ...
        }
        // etc...
    }
}
```

(From [Craig Stuntz](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/23/37947/))

Comment: This would work fine for MVC 1, but might be fragile in MVC 2. MVC 2 won't clear the key until you read it, so if you "forgot" to read it somewhere then there might be a "stale" key in the session.

Comment: Thanks for the highlighting that caveat Craig

Comment: Ah, so ASP.NET MVC's TempData is going to catch up to Rails' "flash hash"? Very nice! I'm liking a lot coming out of MVC 2.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* have the option of adding a parameter to your `Action` method that allows you to pass in a value specifying whether it's a `Controller.RedirectToAction`, a `RedirectToRoute`, or a client browser request.  Couple this with some server variable checks and you may be able to come up with something that works *most* of the time.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string source)
{
    if (source == "")
    {
        // client browser request
    }
    else if (source == "redirectToAction")
    {
        // redirect to action
    }
    else if (source == "redirectToRoute")
    {
        // redirect to route
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Request.ServerVariables["http_referrer"] would be empty if is the action is hit from a redirect to action, I think. Otherwise it would be the URL that corresponds to the action method visited "directly".

Kindness,

Dan